# RecyclerView scroll offset gets reset when adding unrelated view programmatically

Tags: java, android-recyclerview

Whenever I add a TextView on top of RecyclerView, the horizontal scroll offset resets to start.

I have a LinearLayout which contains two items - TextViewContainer and the RecyclerView. After the RecyclerView has initialized, I update the horizontal scroll offset by 100 pixels the following way:

```
 recyclerView.scrollTo( 100, 0 ).
```

Then whenever I add a TextView to the TextViewContainer, the RecyclerView offset gets reset to the start for whatever reason, even though they're not related in any way.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textViewContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

        <RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
     </LinearLayout>
```

I'm adding the TextView the following way:

```
    LinearLayout container = rootView.findViewById( 
    R.layout.textViewContainer );

    TextView textView = new TextView(container.getContext());
    textView.setLayoutParams(new 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextSize( 20.5f );
    textView.setText("TEST" );
    container.removeAllViews();
    container.addView(textView);
```

I'm expecting for the RecyclerView stay at the 100 pixel horizontal offset and NOT to get reset back to 0 when I add a TextView above in a separate container.

The textViewContainer is unrelated to the RecyclerView, I don't understand why it's resetting to the start as soon as I add the TextView to the Text View Container.

The only reason I could think of why this is happening is because each item in the RecyclerView is wider than the screen width and maybe that's why Android is trying to reset the horizontal scroll offset since there has been changes in the main layout, not sure..

Is there any way I can prevent this from happening? Thanks!